# Обмен массивами данных разных частей приложения с точки зрения ООП

Tags: php, шаблоны-проектирования, dto

Допустим, у нас есть массив, полученный из прайс-листа:

```
$items = [
    [
        'article' => 'ART01',
        'price_rub' => 1000,
        'price_usd' => 0,
        'category' => 'Смартфоны',
    ],
    [
        'article' => 'ART02',
        'price_rub' => 0,
        'price_usd' => 500,
        'category' => 'Мониторы',
    ],  
];
```

Необходимо передать этот массив в определённый метод, который добавит туда несколько полей, например так:

```
public function handle(array $params)
{
    if($params['price_rub'] > 0)
        $params['price'] = $params['price_rub'] * 1.1;
    elseif($params['price_usd'] > 0)
        $params['price'] = $params['price_usd'] * 60 * 1.1;

    $params['is_active'] = rand(0, 1);

    return $params;
}
```

И где-то в другом файле:

```
foreach($items as $k => $item)
    $items[$k] = $handler->handle($item);
```

Но работать с массивами не очень удобно и, тем более, не ООПшно.

Знаю, что для подобных вещей используют DTO. Вопрос - нормально ли использовать этот паттерн в данной ситуации? И если да, то как его правильно использовать?

Можно создать 1 класс со всеми полями и делать так:

```
foreach($items as $k => $item)
    $handler->handle($item);
```

Мы ведь передаём ссылку на объект, значит все изменения объекта, произошедшие внутри handle, отразятся и на текущем объекте.

Или можно создать 2 класса, к примеру Item и ItemAfterHandling (поля ведь у них разные, у второго ещё добавляются price и is_active), соответственно первый передаём в метод, второй получаем из метода.

В общем, как правильно решается эта задача с точки зрения ООП?

Comment: почему нельзя просто foreach пройтись и добавить везде нужный параметр?

Comment: @PaulWall я привёл упрощённый пример. По факту в методе handle происходит обращение к другим методам, из базы данных выгружаются формулы для расчёта и т.п. Суть в том, что этот метод добавляет несколько новых значений, которые мне нужно получить.

Comment: массив - основная структура в ПХП. как с ним может быт не удобно работать?

Comment: @teran если передаёшь объект в метод - всегда можно посмотреть список свойств в его классе. Если передаёшь массив - непонятно, какие параметры обязательные, какие не обязательные, какие лишние. Можно написать длинный комментарий к методу с описанием каждого возможного ключа, но тогда, на мой взгляд, вместо описания удобней использовать объект.

Comment: ну дак чего вы исходные модели в виде массива храните тогда? сделайте модель объектом и работайте. какую то проблему из ничего придумали, и пытаетесь прицепить какие-то паттерны. головой надо думать в первую очередь, а не паттернами. Сформируйте классы сущностей согласно логике вашей предметной области. Если это единый объект, то один класс. Если независимые сущности, то разделите на два.

Comment: С точки зрения ООП, вы должны получать массив (а лучше коллекцию) объектов. И вам скорее всего нужен не DTO, а POJO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я так понял задача состоит в передаче объектов с записанными данными в другие файлы для дальнейшей их обработки. Если Вы пишите свою систему без использования готовых фреймворков (laravel, yii, symphony и т.д.), то дл передачи я предлагаю использовать методы сериализации данных. PHP - `serialize()`. Пример:

```
Class PriceController extends ... implements .... 
{
    protected $price;

    public function __construct(Array $price) {
        $this->price = $price;
    }

    public function getPrice() {
        return $this->price;
    }

    public function handle() {
        if($this->price['price_rub'] > 0)
            $this->price['price'] = $this->price['price_rub'] * 1.1;
        elseif($this->price['price_usd'] > 0)
            $this->price['price'] = $this->price['price_usd'] * 60 * 1.1;

        $this->price['is_active'] = rand(0, 1);
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Предположим у Вас есть класс обработки прайс-листа (с Вашим методом handle). В любом файле подключаете класс и создаёте объект:

```
$priceListObj = new PriceController($items);
foreach($priceListObj->getPrice() as $item) {
    // Вывод
}
```

Далее Вам нужно Отправить объект `$priceListObj` в другой файл, тогда

```
$serializePrice = serialize($priceListObj);
```

И сохраняем получившуюся строку в бд или файл и потом просто открываем его в любом месте и вызываем `unserialize()`. Тем самым можете вызывать метод `handle()` как Вы описали выше уже в новом месте со всеми изменениями сделанными ранее